# How to get screen size in Android, including virtual buttons?

Tags: android

For normal uses you can use the DisplayMetrics class and get the "renderable" size, but I want to figure out the actual physical screen size, which includes the virtual buttons height.

On my Galaxy Nexus the reported size no matter what I tried is 1196x720, what can I use to get the physical one which is 1280x720 ? Same goes for Nexus 7, Nexus 4 and Nexus 10 devices.

**UPDATE** : This is the final code I now use, including the fix :

```
    //Activity A = this;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) A.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    Display disp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    int API_LEVEL =  android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (API_LEVEL >= 17)
    {
        disp.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }
    else
    {
        disp.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }

    int Width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int Height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Show the code you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Display.getRealSize(Point)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) From the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html)

> The display area is described in two different ways.
>
> The application display area specifies the part of the display that
> may contain an application window, excluding the system decorations.
>
> The application display area may be smaller than the real display area
> because the system subtracts the space needed for decor elements such
> as the status bar. Use the following methods to query the application
> display area: getSize(Point), getRectSize(Rect) and
> getMetrics(DisplayMetrics).
>
> The real display area specifies the part
> of the display that contains content including the system decorations.
> Even so, the real display area may be smaller than the physical size
> of the display if the window manager is emulating a smaller display
> using (adb shell am display-size). Use the following methods to query
> the real display area: getRealSize(Point),
> getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics).

Comment: Available from API Level 17 ( 4.2 ) onwards !
This basically means that older samsung tablets that don't have the 4.2 update, have no other way to get the real size ?

Comment: You can try with `DisplayMetrics.widthPixels`/`heightPixels` for legacy versions.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work cause I already tried that. Oh well, I needed it for nexus devices mostly, here's to hoping 4.X gets adopted quicker.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Unfortunately the `Display` API (<17) is intended to return only "renderable" area size. It's a shame such a feature has been introduced so late.

Answer (score 4):

The answer in the similar question seems to have a solution to get the real size of the display when API < 17 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699681/601298

```
WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(metrics);
// since SDK_INT = 1;
widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
try {
    widthPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(d);
    heightPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
try {
    Point realSize = new Point();
    Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
    widthPixels = realSize.x;
    heightPixels = realSize.y;
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Comment: Slight note, in case the class Display does not have that method, it will throw java.lang.NoSuchMethodError which is not derived off Exception (it's derived off Throwable) so you won't catch the exception and will crash.

Comment: I have just verified that in this case the java.lang.NoSuchMethodException is thrown (not the NoSuchMethodError), which is derived from Exception, so the code should be ok.

Comment: Why invoke and not directly d.getRealSize(realSize);?

Comment: Pawel Cioch, I think it can be called directly as well. The reflections stuff required only if you build the APK against SDK < 17.